# Siri can no longer find my home #

Tags: iphone, ios, siri

Whenever I wanted to call my land line at home, I would instruct Siri to "call home" (my home number is listed as home in my contact list) She would respond by saying "calling home" and the call would be made. Now she says "I dont have a home number for John" (this is my name). A friend is having the same problem. What has happened?

Comment: No changes made to the phone or contacts whatsoever? No software upgrade?

Comment: Do you still have the "Home" contact?

Comment: @level42 There was no "Home" contact. Per the OP Siri recognized "call home" as him trying to call the phone number labeled "Home" on the contact for "John" (him). Now it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problems, only Siri was not finding contact information of any kind, was not locating my friends, and not opening apps on command. I found that the problem was that Siri was having an issue with opening apps was causing all problems listed. To fix I used a Cydia app called [iFile](http://cydia.saurik.com/package/eu.heinelt.ifile) to locate the following files:

```
/var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.LaunchServices-045.csstore
/var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installation.plist
```

Delete both the files, close iFile, and reboot device. After restarting all your apps will be gone and they will come back one at a time. Took only a few seconds for them all to load. Tested Siri and all my problems solved.

<sup>I'm using a jailbroken iPhone 5 with 6.1.2</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Siri not being able to access some contacts. "Call Joe Smith." Siri responds "I don't have a number for Joe Smith. Did you mean these other names." Then she gives me a list of the all other Smiths except Joe. I thought it was a fluke, but it started to occur with other regularly used contacts. A restart did the trick at least for now. I only restart my phone when I get on a plane, so it had been three weeks since my last shutdown

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings-> Mail, Contacts, Calendars-> My info

and select the contact that you want to be matched with you. Be sure that this contact has a Home number. That's it

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if you resolved this, but I had this problem and discovered that Siri differentiates numbers labeled "mobile" and numbers labeled "home". Setting it to "Home" works, setting it to "Mobile" it doesn't.

This is the top hit for this question via Internet search so I hope this helps and I save some frustration out there.